# Which CRT version is bundled with .NET 3.5?

Tags: .net, deployment, msvcrt

To minimize deployment package, I'd like to know the CRT versions which are already included in .NET redists. The info I've already gathered are:

.NET 2.0 -> CRT 8.0.50727.42

.NET 2.0 SP1 -> CRT 8.0.50727.762

However, I cannot find the CRT versions for .NET 3.5. I roughly remember I used to come across a blog page list all the versions. However, I just cannot google it out again...

Edit:
So it is like this?

.NET 3.5 -> CRT 9.0.21022.8

.NET 3.5 SP1 -> CRT 9.0.30729.1

Answer (score 2, accepted):

9.0.21022.8 I believe.